# Number format exception in kotlin android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, numberformatexception

I need help with this line of code, please. Everything was working perfectly until recently when I started receiving a number format exception. I have parsing the string to Int but not working. I must be missing something from the code.
Below is cartListActivity and the cartItem dataclass the error was referencing

```
 private lateinit var mCartListItem: ArrayList<CartItem>

 for (item in mCartListItem){

               val availableQuantity = item.stock_quantity.toInt()
               if(availableQuantity > 0){
                   // convert the price to double
                   val price = item.product_price.toDouble()
                   // convert the quantity order to Int]
                   val quantity = item.cart_quantity.toInt()
                   // calculate the sub total
                   subTotal += (price * quantity)
               }
           }
```

The cartItem dataclass

```
@Parcelize
data class CartItem(
    val user_id: String = "",
    val product_owner_id: String ="",
    val product_id: String = "",
    val product_title: String = "",
    val product_price: String = "",
    val product_image: String = "",
    var cart_quantity: String = "",
    var stock_quantity: String = "",
    var id:String = ""
): Parcelable
```

The error....

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: jdd.com.ng.jddwebmaster.jddstore, PID: 10066
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:650)
    at jdd.com.ng.jddwebmaster.jddstore.code.ui.activities.CartListActivity.successfullyGetCartItemList(CartListActivity.kt:100) at jdd.com.ng.jddwebmaster.jddstore.code.cloud_firestore.FirestoreClass.getCartList$lambda-23(FirestoreClass.kt:312)
    at jdd.com.ng.jddwebmaster.jddstore.code.cloud_firestore.FirestoreClass.$r8$lambda$FrIDmKdK751gNKq_VZzfWyc0vVk(Unknown Source:0)
    at jdd.com.ng.jddwebmaster.jddstore.code.cloud_firestore.FirestoreClass$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17.onSuccess(Unknown Source:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzm.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6819)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:497)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:912)
```

Comment: is the issue on availableQuanitity, price or quanitity?

Comment: The issue on the availableQuanitity

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you exactly what the problem is:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:627)
```

What number should an empty string be parsed as? You can't, it's an invalid string to represent a number, that's why you're getting a `NumberFormatException`. (You get these when there's something about the string that makes it an unrecognised format for a number.)

So you have two `toInt()` calls there:

`val availableQuantity = item.stock_quantity.toInt()`

`val quantity = item.cart_quantity.toInt()`

One of those is failing (the line number on the error tells you which one), because either `stock_quantity` or `cart_quantity` is an *empty `String`*. That's also the default value for all your fields in `CartItem`.

So something about how those items are being constructed is going wrong, and you're not supplying all the data you need to. You'll have to investigate and find out where it's happening. I'd recommend debugging it ([here's how if you've never done it before](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug), it's extremely useful and helpful to know!), otherwise start logging stuff and find out where those invalid `CartItem`s are appearing.

(Although from your stacktrace it looks like this data's coming directly from Firebase - so are you fetching it correctly? Is it being *stored* there correctly?)

Comment: Thank you for the explanations, it helped so much... After debugging several with no success, I deleted all the data from the backend and deleted all users. It worked afterwards with all new registered users and data without giving a number format exception.

Comment: @Adewale no worries! In future though, it would be helpful to know *why* it was going wrong - if you release your app and you have real user data, deleting it all would be a big deal and a last resort, right? I'd have set a breakpoint and debugged where you receive the data from Firebase (or at least log it) - that way you'll know if there's a problem with *the data itself* (which it sounds like there was) and you can work out how it happened, and how to fix it or handle the bad data in the app

Comment: Like (as a hypothetical example) it's possible you made changes to the way data is stored, maybe adding a new field in your `CartItem`, and storing a value for that when you upload to Firebase. But if you had old data stored, which is missing that value, all your default values in `CartItem` are *null* - so it would handle missing data in that older format by basically crashing the app. It might be better to use a safe fallback value (`"0"`?) so it can still handle the old format, and maybe look at converting all your stored data to the new format within Firebase. Updates and changes happen!